# tar_fdopen with file descriptor previously used

Tags: c, sockets, tar

I'm using **libtar** to write a client-server that sends the archive to the server via sockets.

This code works (server side):

```
socket_fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0));

bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_MIGRATION_COPY);

bind(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

listen(socket_fd,1);    // Only 1 client

size_addr_cl = sizeof(addr_cl);
socket_cl = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr_cl, &size_addr_cl); // Wait until client arrives

tar_fdopen(&tar, socket_cl, NULL, NULL, O_RDONLY, 0644, 0);
tar_extract_all(tar, path);
tar_close(tar);
close(socket_fd);
```

Further I need to read an integer before the archive, so I put:

```
read(socket_fd, (char *)&number,sizeof(int));
```

just before `tar_fd_open`, and add the corresponding line in the client:

```
 write(socket_fd, (char *)&number,sizeof(int));
```

Bad news, the tar extract stops working and I cannot figure out why. Why a previously read/write can interfer with the next operation on the file descriptor?

Comment: I don't think that `tar_fdopen()` actually works properly with sockets in the first place!  You are probably getting lucky and seeing it work, but it will not be reliable because libtar does not check for "short reads" when extracting files.  See here: http://sourcecodebrowser.com/libtar/1.2.11/extract_8c.html - see it does ` k = tar_block_read(t, buf); if (k != T_BLOCKSIZE)` and treats it as an error if the written size is less than `T_BLOCKSIZE`.  That will not be reliable with TCP sockets, because a read might produce fewer bytes than requested even if more will come later on!

Comment: ...I think doing this correctly and reliably will require that you implement your own `type` for libtar where you implement read with a loop to continue looking for data until all the required bytes are consumed.

Comment: regarding this line: `read(socket_fd, (char *)&number,sizeof(int));`   it seems the spelling for the socket variable name is not defined.  perhaps you meant: `read(socket_cl, (char *)&number,sizeof(int));`

Comment: @John Zwinck why? I mean, in a blocking socket why k should be different from T_BLOCKSIZE? (If there are no errors in communication). It seems working right now

Comment: Because TCP doesn't work that way. Short writes happen when the network gets busy. Your code may work fine now but it is definitely not safe and correct. It will fail in some conditions which are not rare. You have been warned.

Comment: Ok, it should be sufficient to add `MSG_WAITALL` to the recv function inside the libtar.

Comment: Or simply pass a different function for reading to `tartype_t` to fdopen ;)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found the stupid bug, I'm reading from socket_fd instead of socket_cl! Damnit.

Comment: I noted this when reading the posted question (see my comment below the question.   How come your compiler did not catch this?   When compiling, always enable alll the warning,s, then fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: Why? It's not an error, socket_fd exists but it's the accepting socket not the client socket